# Why does it give me an error no "operator=="?

Tags: c++

This line is an error and I don't know why. The compiler is telling me that the string array can't be converted to a string variable. The search is a string variable the user types in to look for names. And the names[count] is checking through an array of names.

```
string search;
string names[5]={};
for(int count=0; count<5; count++)
{
    cout<<"Enter a name"<<endl;
    cin>>names[count];
}
cout<<"Names entered"<<endl;
for(int count=0; count<5; count++)
{
    cout<<names[count]<<endl;
    cout<<"What name would you like to search for"<<endl;
    cin>>search;
    for(int count=0; count<5; count++)
    {
        if(names[count]=search)
        {
            cout<<search<<"is on array "<<count<<endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout<<search<<"is not on the list"<<endl;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you want `=` or `==`? What are the types of the given variables? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I'll add more of the code.

Comment: You seem to want `names[count]==search`.

Comment: Please add the complete compiler message. `no "operator=="` can be said in many different ways, possibly being a non declared overloaded comparison operator or an invalid assignment

Answer (score 2):

Is giving you this error because you are using the `=` assignment operator instead of the `==` comparison operator. Only use the former when assigning values to variables and the second for comparing variables in a condition.

I hope this helps:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/what-is-the-difference-between-assignment-and-equal-to-operators/

Have a good one and happy hacking!

Comment: Even with a link, try to provide a small snippet of code that describes the difference between the 2 operators.

Answer (score 0):

Your question title mentions `operator==`, but there is no use of `operator==` anywhere in the code you have shown.

Your search logic is all wrong, though.  First off, it is in the wrong place, it should not be inside the 2nd `for` loop at all, it needs to be moved up 1 level.  And second, it is using the assignment `operator=` when it should be using the comparison `operator==` instead.  And third, it is handling its output incorrectly.

Try something more like this instead:

```
string search;
string names[5];

for(int count = 0; count < 5; ++count)
{
    cout << "Enter a name" << endl;
    cin >> names[count];
}

cout << "Names entered" << endl;
for(int count = 0; count < 5; ++count)
{
    cout << names[count] << endl;
}

cout << "What name would you like to search for" << endl;
cin >> search;

int found = -1;
for(int count = 0; count < 5; ++count)
{
    if (names[count] == search)
    {
        found = count;
        break;
    }
}

if (found != -1)
{
    cout << search << " is on array " << found << endl;
}
else
{
    cout << search << " is not on the list" << endl;
}


/* alternatively:

#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

string *namesEnd = &names[5];
if (std::find(names, namesEnd, search) != namesEnd)
{
    cout << search << " is on array " << std::distance(names, found) << endl;
}
else
{
    cout << search << " is not on the list" << endl;
}
*/
```